# Saving Image in Blob Format (On converting in blob format is getting wrong)

Tags: php, blob

On converting image in blob format getting wrong format and mysql is not allow to open getting error not a valid format.

```
$filePath = $targetDir."/".$_FILES['productimage']["name"];
$photopath1 = $_FILES['productimage']["name"];
$blobImg=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['productimage']["tmp_name"]));
                    
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productimage']["tmp_name"], $filePath)){    
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filePath = $targetDir."/".$_FILES['productimage']["name"];
$photopath1 = $_FILES['productimage']["name"];
$check=($_FILES['productimage']["tmp_name"]);

$imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["productimage"]["tmp_name"]);

          
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productimage']["tmp_name"], $filePath)){
    return 1;
}
```